# Outer apply in sql server makes my query works slowly

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have this query

```
select *
from    joints c
```

The execution time is 14 sec.Every joints rows has a id .I should pass this id to another query to get other information as you can see :

```
SELECT    top 1    dbo.NdtReportDetails.RequestNumber AS MasterRTRequestNumber, dbo.NdtReports.NdtReportNumber AS ContractorRTRequestNumber,NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportDatetime AS RTDate, NdtReportDetails.Defect as RTDefect,
                         dbo.NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportNumber AS ContractorRTReportNumber,NdtReportDetails.Remark as RTSegment
FROM            dbo.NdtReportDetails LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.NdtReports ON dbo.NdtReportDetails.ReportId = dbo.NdtReports.Id 
        where NdtReportDetails.JointId=c.Id  and NdtReportDetails.NdtType='RT'  order by NdtReportDetails.Id desc
```

So the final query :

```
select *


from    joints c
    outer  Apply 
    (SELECT    top 1    dbo.NdtReportDetails.RequestNumber AS MasterRTRequestNumber, dbo.NdtReports.NdtReportNumber AS ContractorRTRequestNumber,NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportDatetime AS RTDate, NdtReportDetails.Defect as RTDefect,
                         dbo.NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportNumber AS ContractorRTReportNumber,NdtReportDetails.Remark as RTSegment
FROM            dbo.NdtReportDetails LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.NdtReports ON dbo.NdtReportDetails.ReportId = dbo.NdtReports.Id 
        where NdtReportDetails.JointId=c.Id  and NdtReportDetails.NdtType='RT'  order by NdtReportDetails.Id desc) b


        outer  Apply 
    (SELECT    top 1    dbo.NdtReportDetails.RequestNumber AS MasterRTRequestNumber, dbo.NdtReports.NdtReportNumber AS ContractorRTRequestNumber,NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportDatetime AS RTDate, NdtReportDetails.Defect as RTDefect,
                         dbo.NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportNumber AS ContractorRTReportNumber,NdtReportDetails.Remark as RTSegment
FROM            dbo.NdtReportDetails LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.NdtReports ON dbo.NdtReportDetails.ReportId = dbo.NdtReports.Id 
        where NdtReportDetails.JointId=c.Id  and NdtReportDetails.NdtType='PT'  order by NdtReportDetails.Id desc) d

    outer  Apply 
    (SELECT    top 1    dbo.NdtReportDetails.RequestNumber AS MasterRTRequestNumber, dbo.NdtReports.NdtReportNumber AS ContractorRTRequestNumber,NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportDatetime AS RTDate, NdtReportDetails.Defect as RTDefect,
                         dbo.NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportNumber AS ContractorRTReportNumber,NdtReportDetails.Remark as RTSegment
FROM            dbo.NdtReportDetails LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.NdtReports ON dbo.NdtReportDetails.ReportId = dbo.NdtReports.Id 
        where NdtReportDetails.JointId=c.Id  and NdtReportDetails.NdtType='PWHT'  order by NdtReportDetails.Id desc) m


        outer  Apply 
    (SELECT    top 1    dbo.NdtReportDetails.RequestNumber AS MasterRTRequestNumber, dbo.NdtReports.NdtReportNumber AS ContractorRTRequestNumber,NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportDatetime AS RTDate, NdtReportDetails.Defect as RTDefect,
                         dbo.NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportNumber AS ContractorRTReportNumber,NdtReportDetails.Remark as RTSegment
FROM            dbo.NdtReportDetails LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.NdtReports ON dbo.NdtReportDetails.ReportId = dbo.NdtReports.Id 
        where NdtReportDetails.JointId=c.Id  and NdtReportDetails.NdtType='MT'  order by NdtReportDetails.Id desc) o

        outer  Apply 
    (SELECT    top 1    dbo.NdtReportDetails.RequestNumber AS MasterRTRequestNumber, dbo.NdtReports.NdtReportNumber AS ContractorRTRequestNumber,NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportDatetime AS RTDate, NdtReportDetails.Defect as RTDefect,
                         dbo.NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportNumber AS ContractorRTReportNumber,NdtReportDetails.Remark as RTSegment
FROM            dbo.NdtReportDetails LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.NdtReports ON dbo.NdtReportDetails.ReportId = dbo.NdtReports.Id 
        where NdtReportDetails.JointId=c.Id  and NdtReportDetails.NdtType='UT'  order by NdtReportDetails.Id desc) u
        order by c.Id
```

The execution time is 45 sec.So is there any better solution to make this query works faster ?
[image]

I am using indexes to make better performance .

My query

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.JointHistory c
       OUTER Apply (SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties 
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN NRD.RequestNumber END) AS RT_MasterRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN NR.NdtReportNumber END) AS RT_ContractorRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN NRD.ResponseReportDatetime END) AS RT_RTDate,
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN NRD.Defect END) AS RT_RTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN NRD.ResponseReportNumber END) AS RT_ContractorRTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN NRD.Remark END) AS RT_RTSegment,
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN NRD.RequestNumber END) AS PT_MasterRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN NR.NdtReportNumber END) AS PT_ContractorRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN NRD.ResponseReportDatetime END) AS PT_RTDate,
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN NRD.Defect END) AS PT_RTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN NRD.ResponseReportNumber END) AS PT_ContractorRTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NRD.NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN NRD.Remark END) AS PT_RTSegment                 

                    FROM   NRD NRD
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN NdtReports NR
                                        ON NRD.ReportId = NR.Id
                    WHERE  NRD.JointId = c.Id
                           AND NRD.NdtType IN ( 'RT', 'PT', 'PWHT', 'MT', 'UT' )
                    ORDER  BY NRD.Id DESC) b
```

Comment: index not working, because 15 second is full table scan timing

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov yes you are right .it didn't work

Comment: [Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) is probably part of the problem.  If you can provide a MCVE it would be much easier to answer (see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on this).

Comment: Aliasing your tables would make the code an awful lot more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your query can be simplified like this

```
SELECT *
FROM   joints c
       OUTER Apply (SELECT Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS RT_MasterRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS RT_ContractorRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS RT_RTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN Defect END) AS RT_RTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS RT_ContractorRTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN Remark END) AS RT_RTSegment,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS PT_MasterRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS PT_ContractorRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS PT_RTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN Defect END) AS PT_RTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS PT_ContractorRTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN Remark END) AS PT_RTSegment,
                           ....
                    FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties NRD.NdtType,
                                                   NRD.RequestNumber,
                                                   NR.NdtReportNumber,
                                                   NRD.ResponseReportDatetime,
                                                   NRD.Defect,
                                                   NRD.ResponseReportNumber,
                                                   NRD.Remark
                            FROM   dbo.NdtReportDetails NRD
                                   LEFT OUTER JOIN NdtReports NR
                                                ON NRD.ReportId = NR.Id
                            WHERE  NRD.JointId = c.Id
                                   AND NRD.NdtType IN ( 'RT', 'PT', 'PWHT', 'MT', 'UT' )
                            ORDER  BY NdtReportDetails.Id DESC) i)b
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "dbo.NdtReportDetails.RequestNumber" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "dbo.NdtReports.NdtReportNumber" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "NdtReportDetails.ResponseReportDatetime" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "NdtReportDetails.Defect" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier ...

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Your `THEN` clause is not using aliases

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - updated the alias issue. Regarding `..` you need to fill the query with remaining `NRD.NdtTypes`

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'NRD'.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - Post the full query you are executing in question

Comment: I added to my post

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - check now updated.. Mistakenly replaced `dbo.NdtReportDetails` with `NRD`

Comment: Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Column "dbo.NdtReportDetails.Id" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
The multi-part identifier "NdtReportDetails.Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "NRD.NdtType" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "NRD.NdtType" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "NRD.NdtType" could not be bound.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - Updated.. start debugging the mistakes bro.. these are  simple mistakes.. I dont have schema setup to check so am missing few things.. check now

Comment: Just guess the execution time ?

Comment: 4 sec :Amazing :|||||| how ?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - now hitting the `dbo.NdtReportDetails` and `NdtReports` table once instead of 5 times

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this....

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT C.*
     , RD.RequestNumber         AS MasterRTRequestNumber
     , R.NdtReportNumber        AS ContractorRTRequestNumber
     , RD.ResponseReportDatetime AS RTDate
     , RD.Defect                as RTDefect
     , RD.ResponseReportNumber  AS ContractorRTReportNumber
     , RD.Remark                as RTSegment
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Id , RD.NdtType ORDER BY RD.Id DESC) rn 
FROM        dbo.NdtReportDetails RD
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.NdtReports   R ON RD.ReportId = R.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.joints       c ON RD.JointId=c.Id
where RD.NdtType IN ('RT','PT' , 'PWHT' , 'MT' ,'UT')
)
SELECT * 
FROM X 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: 1.54 sec execution time

Answer (score 0):

create one field index on fields in where condition, for example on JointId field:

```
CREATE INDEX ndx_NdtReportDetails_JId ON NdtReportDetails (JointId);
... more indexes here...
```

do not create 2 field indexes or index for fixed value fields (for example NdtType field)

Comment: i create an index on jointid in NdtReportDetails  but same time

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any "NdtReportDetails" records without linked "NdtReports" record?
Is it even possible? So, don't use LEFT JOIN in your subqueries. Use INNER JOIN, i think it will help.